# What's the fastest way to kill a server?

Tags: kill

For the heck of it, what's the fastest way to kill a server, other than just pulling the plug?

Kill as in a(n) (un)safe shutdown, you could theoretically reboot it and have it survive the incident.

Edit: Tangentially related to serverfault.com, my apologies. IMHO, the question is related in that these are possible things users could be attempting, as well as in the case of adverse conditions there might be reasons server admins want to take down multiple boxes lest undefined "damage" might occur.

Edit2: opened to community wiki.

Comment: How is this related to system administration?

Comment: @Zoredache: straw clutching here, but the answers could provide a useful list of things to watch out for our more dangerous users trying...

Comment: C4 ;) kills the server with 8040 meters per second which IS fast ;)

Comment: Bazookas always work well.

Comment: I would say that exposing the server to a naked singularity (i.e. a black hole) at zero range would make it go offline quicker.

Comment: I strongly suggest reopening it as a community wiki. It's a really fun question, and quite technically interesting, too.

Comment: Too bad it's closed... I just found this, and it definitely qulifies: http://vimeo.com/11344216.

Comment: you're right, that's perfect. What fun!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

On a Sun server, `Stop-A` suspends the kernel immediately.  You can press the key combination or send an equivalent signal on the serial console.

On Linux, `Alt-SysRq-O` crashes the kernel immediately.  Through a remote shell, you can do `echo o > /proc/sysrq-trigger`.  There are other [magic SysRq keys](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_SysRq_key) that will cause an immediate unclean reboot.  `Alt-SysRq-S` is handy to sync to disk first.

Comment: Bingo, cheers mate.

Comment: I'd like to add that "echo b > /proc/sysrq-trigger" is useful when an NFS client is wedged so badly that a clean reboot is likely to hang forever.  In that case, I would rather take the chance of local filesystem corruption (which is unlikely to be a problem with journaling) than to be left with a remote server that is unreachable because SSH has shut down and NFS hangs while trying to unmount.

Comment: I shall have to try that next time our VM running Zimbra decides it neither wants to work or properly shut down. `echo S > /proc/sysrq-trigger` followed by `echo 0 > /proc/sysrq-trigger` should be slightly safer than just hitting the virtual bit red button.

Answer (score 15):

give an oracle dba the root password.

Comment: You'd really have to *hate* that poor server to do **that**!!!

Answer (score 7):

C4, or other explosive

Comment: Question stated "have it reboot and survive the incident". C4 would not let it do that.

Comment: It would with remote detonator. User would survive ;)

Comment: @TomTom, excellent. :D

Comment: thermite. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jhfF2Et77aw

Answer (score 7):

For Windows, this one is simply *delicious*:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff545499(v=VS.85).aspx

Just a little Registry edit, and you'll be able to trigger an instant BSOD on any Windows system by pressing `CTRL + SCROLL LOCK` twice.

Comment: Oohh, nice - I didn't know about this

Comment: Well, there *should* be some way to force a system crash in order to test and debug it, I suppose... MS developers couldn't just sit there waiting for it to randomly happen. Even if in good old times this wouldn't have meant waiting *so much* :-p

Answer (score 6):

You're not scaling.  If it doesn't scale, it's not a solution.

EMP pulse.

Theoretically, if it didn't hard-fry the electronics, you could reinstall the OS and things would survive the incident.  Fastest way to turn off an entire datacenter of machines -- just use a larger pulse -- and will work better than just pulling the power, as those UPSes/batteries won't get in your way.

Of course, it's not ideal scaling, as you're dealing inverse-square law for power vs coverage area and any decent computer scientist will wince at such an O constraint and look for a better algorithm.  Perhaps a bunch of EMP pulse emitters, each triggerable by being subjected to a pulse, would give you an easy scaling cascade system, at the cost of small delays in the effect as the pulses ripple out.

Comment: Wow, I like that. Wire them all together and have one box shielded (or not for that matter) set off localised EMPs throughout your data centre. Scalable and fun.

Answer (score 3):

Universal: Find a paperclip and jam it in the "Reset" hole

Comment: ...or in the power supply. But be sure to have good insulation...

Answer (score 3):

Run a [fork bomb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_bomb) as root? (or any user if no user resource limits are in place)

Or cat hair, dust, and other general household detritus gumming up all the cooling fans?

Comment: Ah, good old fork bombs...

Answer (score 3):

This is handy for shutting down a Windows computer remotely:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32\shutdown.exe -r -m \\MYCOMPUTERNAME01
C:\WINDOWS\system32\shutdown.exe -r -m \\192.168.1.186

-r means you are completely shutting it down and rebooting
-m means it's a remote machine
```

Comment: The `-f` and `-t` flags could be of some assistance here.

Answer (score 3):

For Windows:

```
shutdown -s -f -t 0 \\ServerName
```

This forces an immediate shutdown and causes all the applications to close (whether they'd like to or not).

Answer (score 2):

`shutdown -t now` has always been fast enough for me

Comment: sure, but that's no fun! That's the nice, pleasant, clean way of killing a server where it shuts down all running processes, kills the daemons, and stops.

Comment: @Eric: I took your parentheses in "a(n) (un)safe" to indicate both alternatives.

Comment: @Dennis, fair enough. I should've worded that more clearly.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your system

```
halt --force
```

might get the job done (as far as quickness goes).

Comment: I'll look in to it, thanks. I've never used the force option of halt.

Answer (score 1):

Cross the pins in a USB port with something metal (paper clip works well), and you'll have a really quick power down (ie, instant).  I've only ever seen this happen in a laptop, but I'd imagine it'd happen on a desktop as well.  Amazingly, the computer has booted back up normally after it was done.

Comment: Interesting, hadn't heard of that before, something to try next time.

Comment: P.S. - Only try it if you're ok with frying the whole computer in case something goes wrong. :)

Comment: On a similar note, get a usb cable and plug both ends into the same computer. You'll certainly fry some components that way.

Comment: [According to this blog post,](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/11/29/1171695.aspx) USB 2.0 devices are now required to withstand short-circuits.

Answer (score 1):

Two fun ones that may not give you 'comes back up' (data corruption is vicious):

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/mem
dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/kmem
```

Of course, the other way around would be interesting too.

Comment: What OSs have a /dev/mem? I run ubuntu, and there wasn't a /dev/mem last I checked

Comment: Linux xxx 2.6.32-xx-generic xxx-Ubuntu SMP Mon Jul 5 09:20:59 UTC 2010 x86_64 GNU/Linux \\ $ ls -l /dev/mem 
crw-r----- 1 root kmem 1, 1 2010-07-14 00:02 /dev/mem